# Do I need to install Boost to build odeint?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, ode, odeint

I am trying to solve ODE by using odeint package. The odeint website provides a download on their package. I downloaded the zip file included it in my project but it doesn't work.

I understand that if I download the whole boost package, it automatically includes odeint. I have succeeded on doing this.

But my question is "can I directly download the odeint files from odeint website and build it from there without installing the whole boost libraries??"

In our situation, we do not have enough time to ask students to download and build boost in class.

i.e. only download the odeint from the following website
http://headmyshoulder.github.io/odeint-v2/downloads.html
or
Github link
https://github.com/headmyshoulder/odeint-v2

Comment: And did you just try installing it without installing boost?

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply!! I downloaded odeint and I didn't find anything that I can install or build. Then I download the boost package which has boostrap.bat. I couldn't find something in odeint package that I can build on. I am new to this, Some help is really appreciated.

Comment: http://headmyshoulder.github.io/odeint-v2/doc/boost_numeric_odeint/getting_started/usage__compilation__headers.html states that all the code is contained in the headers, meaning it is all template code. The state vector needs to satisfy the assumptions in http://headmyshoulder.github.io/odeint-v2/doc/boost_numeric_odeint/odeint_in_detail/state_types__algebras_and_operations.html, there should be no problem using the provided examples, it does not have to be `boost::array`.

Answer (score 2):

No, you need to have the boost libraries. At least they need the headers need to be found. You can use odeint additional to the boost installation.

Nevertheless. If you use the latest version from boost you also get odeint, since it is contain in boost.

Comment: So, if I only donwload the odeint packages from http://headmyshoulder.github.io/odeint-v2/downloads.html. They are not enough? Right?

Comment: Yes, you need boost.